# How can I display an array of strings of an object as spans in a JS template literal?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects, template-literals

I have an array of objects. In each object there is a `key` with a `value` of an array of strings (the number of strings changes in each object). How can I display each string of the array as `<span>` in a `JS` template literal?

If the array contains 2 strings, than 2 `<span>` should appear,
If 3 strings, 3 `<span>` etc.

Code:

```js
let items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "item 1",
  "captionTags": ["Stills", "Animation", "Virtual Reality"]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "item 2",
  "captionTags": ["Configurator", "Animation", "Application"]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "item 3",
  "captionTags": ["Stills", "Configurator"]
}];

function displayItems() {
  let itemsContainer = document.querySelector('.items-container');
  itemsContainer.innerHTML = '';
  items.forEach(item => {

    itemsContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="items-wrapper">
        <div class="item-caption">
            <span class="item-caption-col">
                <h3>${item.name}</h3>
                <span class="item-caption-tags">
                I WANT TO DISPLAY HERE EACH ELEMENT OF CAPTION TAGS ARRAY IN EACH OBJECT 
               AS SPANS 
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>`
  });
};


displayItems();
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Just iterate through `item.captionTags`, wrap the strings in `<span>` and append them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the items, and `map` over the tags returning string literals. But because `map` returns a new array just make sure you [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it up into a string at the end.

```js
const items=[{id:1,name:"item 1",captionTags:["Stills","Animation","Virtual Reality"]},{id:2,name:"item 2",captionTags:["Configurator","Animation","Application"]},{id:3,name:"item 3",captionTags:["Stills","Configurator"]}];

function displayItems(items) {
  return items.map(item => {
    const captions = item.captionTags.map(tag => `<span>${tag}</span>`).join('');
    return (
      `<h3>${item.name}</h3><div>${captions}</div>`
    );
  }).join('');
}

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = displayItems(items);
```

```html
<div />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let items = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "item 1",
        "captionTags": ["Stills", "Animation", "Virtual Reality"]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "item 2",
        "captionTags": ["Configurator", "Animation", "Application"]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "item 3",
        "captionTags": ["Stills", "Configurator"]
    }];

function displayItems() {
    let itemsContainer = document.querySelector('.items-container');
    itemsContainer.innerHTML = '';
    items.forEach(item => {

        itemsContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="items-wrapper">
        <div class="item-caption">
            <span class="item-caption-col">
                <h3>${item.name}</h3>
                `;
                item.captionTags.forEach(tag => {
                  itemsContainer.innerHTML +=`<span class="item-caption-tags"> ${tag} </span>`
                })
               itemsContainer.innerHTML +=`
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>`
    });
};


displayItems();
```

```css
span.item-caption-tags {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-container" > </div>
```

`css` is for example only